# How to make a discord.py bot store info on users?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been making a discord.py bot with a profile system that will allow users to add info to their own profiles and see profiles of other members. I got the actual profile embed figured out, but I'm not sure how I would allow the users to change their profile info. I want it so that using a command ~switchcode  (user puts code here) will update their profile. From other posts I've seen, Im guessing I would need a JSON file, but I'm not sure how that works.

A picture of the profile embed so far.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A couple of options are [JSON](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/) and [SQLite](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/) for persistent storage with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, I have used SQL for that, and I think that SQLite or MySQL are good options for this use case. You would have to learn some SQL, but I think that some SQL database will be one of if not the best options for this. My bots use SQL just fine for storing data. I use discord id as a primary key for example.

Comment: You can also use `MongoDB` which is simpler in my opinion. with free 512 MB of data which is a lotttt for text only

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but any idea how I would integrate that with the bot?

Comment: The way I do it, and I use MySQL is to use mysql.connector. Honestly, I watched freecodecamp's video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXV3zeQKqGY) on how to set the db itself up. Then you follow Oracle's rather vague instructions on how to setup MySQL Connector, and then you use it by pulling stuff from it like ```people = mycursor.execute("SELECT discord_id FROM discordpy.pumpkinvalues")```